# Unable to find proper driver for Mysql conneciton

Tags: java, mysql, connection

After long but unsuccessed tries with hibernate, I decided to do my project with native mysql connection.
I got "No suitable driver found" error, necessary parts of my code :

```
    static public Connection DatabaseConnection() {
    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mobil";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "thisPasswordShouldntBeHere";

    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection(url , userName, password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

I've added mysql connector to my project's build path.
At this part of the code I get null value which leads to null pointer exception ;
`conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url , userName, password);`

Stacktrace =

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:msql://localhost:3306/mobil
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at DAO.DatabaseConnection.DatabaseConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:19)
    at DAO.LogIn.SaveDatabase(LogIn.java:48)
    at DAO.LogIn.RegisterUsers(LogIn.java:18)
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DAO.LogIn.SaveDatabase(LogIn.java:63)
    at DAO.LogIn.RegisterUsers(LogIn.java:18)
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace that you can post?

Comment: For know this is an desktop app, so I don't have web-inf or lib.

Comment: Editting the question for stack trace

Comment: Is that stack trace definately correct? Is shows the connection string as starting with jdbc:msql instead of jdbc:mysql.

Comment: I've re-run the project and stack trace is still same. 
It's kinda obvious that the url appears as "msql"

Comment: @UğurcanŞengit It looks all good to me. I think problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: @smit where could it be? Do u have any opinion? :)

Comment: @UğurcanŞengit From what I see in your code. I can make only probability that `1.` Make sure you have `mobil` as your DB Name. `2. ` Make sure you have `userName` and `password` correct. `3.` Make sure you have specified jar included in your classpath. Moreover I don't know why your stackstrace showing different as pointed by Niall Thompson.

Comment: @smit I've done things u said, still doesn't wotk but thanks for help :)

Comment: @UğurcanŞengit This is last I can suggest you. Try another mysql jar. This could be possibility that jar could be corrupt which I found rare. But its worth to try.